# Wait for workspace job to finish

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Background:
I am creating a plug-in that triggers another plug-in's command. This command does a check (background process) and implements markers on specific programs.

Problem:
I have successfully programmatically triggered the command however, I need to wait for it to finish because if I don't wait, I will only get NULL set of markers[].

So far, here is what I have

```
IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IResource resource = workspace.getRoot();
resource.deleteMarkers(null, true, 0);
markers = resource.findMarkers(IMarker.MARKER, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F2);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);    
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F2);

//...command is executed, now running background process
//...wait for all background process to finish

for (IMarker m : markers) {
    System.out.println("Id: " + m.getId());
    System.out.println("Message: " + m.getAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE));
    System.out.println("Line Number: " + m.getAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER));  
}
```

I have tried implementing this

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().run(new IWorkspaceRunnable() {
    public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {

    }
}, new NullProgressMonitor());
```

as explained from here: https://dzone.com/articles/eclipse-gui-testing-is-viable-

> 3. Instead of using sleep() to wait for something to be done, wait for the real thing to be done. A heavily loaded machine can cause
>      processing times to vary. Instead of having a fragile sleep(500L), use
>      a reliable technique to determine when the job is really done.
>
> For example, if you know that your processing is holding a resource
>   lock, post a no-op empty workspace job and wait on it inside your
>   test. It will only be invoked once all other resource locks are
>   released, so when it's complete you're guaranteed that your other job
>   is done

But I guess I am implementing it wrongly because it does not wait for the background jobs to finish.

Any advice on what to do will definitely help!

Edit: To add on, the job/task/process that was executed is from another plug-in that I do not know of. Hence, I do not know the job group, etc. All I'm relying on is waiting for the task to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try to use **IJobManager**:

```
private void waitJobsComplete() {
  final IJobManager manager = Job.getJobManager();
  final Job[] jobs = manager.find(null); //return all jobs
  while(jobExists(jobs)) {
    sleep(50);
  }
}
private boolean jobExists(Job[] jobs) {
   for(Job job: jobs) {
     if(job.getState() != Job.NONE) {
      return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you! However, this will freeze the whole Eclipse workbench as it is running on the same thread. I cannot put it in async as that will not wait for the background processes to finish.

Answer (score 0):

The article you reference is talking about `WorkspaceJob`, you would do what it suggests using something like:

```
Job job = new WorkspaceJob("name")
{
  @Override
  public IStatus runInWorkspace(IProgressMonitor monitor)
    throws CoreException
  {
    return Status.OK_STATUS;
  }
};

job.schedule();

try
 {
   job.join();
 }
catch (InterruptedException e)
 {
   //
 }
```

Comment: Hi @greg-449, thank you. However, when I tried it, it is not waiting for background processes to finish. The code still continues, am I missing something or is there another approach to this?

Comment: Since you haven' told us what command you are running it is impossible to say what you need to do to wait for completion.

Comment: Hi @greg-449, basically it does a code check of the currently open program in the editor. After the check, it opens its own view and displays the problems/markers.